# 3 kinds of objects, random in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have to make a function with parameter of a length of an array. The array should have some objects in it,in random order and random number of any kind of objects. I have 3 kinds of objects like below:

```
   var bestaccount=function(){
   var amount=0;
   this.pay=function(howmuch){amount+=howmuch;};
   this.widthdraw=function(howmuch){amount-=howmuch;};
   this.saldo=function(){return amount;};
   };

   var toGive= function(){
   var amount=0;
   this.pay=function(howmuch){amount+=howmuch;};
   this.saldo=function(){return amount;};
   };

   var toWithdraw=function(){
   var amount=0;
   this.withdraw=function(howmuch){amount-=howmuch;};
   this.saldo=function(){return amount;};
   };
```

How can I put random kind of object in the array?

Answer (score 0):

This snippet illustrates how to do it for a single object, I hope it helps.

The idea is to create an array of references, then pick a random element of the array and construct it.

```
var objects = [
    bestaccount,
    toGive,
    toWithdraw
]

var RandomObject = new objects[Math.floor(Math.random()*objects.length)]();
```

Comment: Yes, it helped a lot! So simple so clever. Thank you!